# Threading problem with some old code

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, thread-safety

I'm on a project that recently upgraded from .net 1.1 to .net 4.0.  We're getting an error from a custom "ThreadPool" class (yes, someone felt the need to write thier own), and now I'm wondering what it might be.

The error is thrown from the following code:

```
    private void Submit(WorkItem work)
    {
        this.AdjustPoolSize();

        lock (this.workQueue.SyncRoot)
        {
        //Monitor.Enter(workQueue);
        this.workQueue.Enqueue(work);
            Monitor.Pulse(this.workQueue.SyncRoot);
        //Monitor.Exit(workQueue);
        }
    }
```

The commented code is how I was handed the code.  Unfortunatly, I don't know much about this project at all and am only here to fix this issue.  The error we see is :

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Object synchronization method was called from an unsynchronized block of code.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjPulse(Object obj)
       at System.Threading.Monitor.Pulse(Object obj)
       at CustomThreadPoolObject.Submit(WorkItem work) in D:\...\Threading.cs:line 1438
       at CustomThreadPoolObject.Submit(WaitCallback callback, Object state) in D:\...\Threading.cs:line 1349
       at SomeGroupProcessFunctionality.Submit(PooledThread thread, TaskInfo task, String appServer, Hashtable batchHandleTable) in D:\...\ProcessGroup.cs:line 143
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Message.Dispatch(Object target, Boolean fExecuteInContext)
       at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, Int32 methodPtr, Boolean fExecuteInContext)
  InnerException:
```

By the looks of it, something is being triggered as "available" when it really isn't.  I tried to google this and found http://bbellomo.blogspot.com/2007/03/object-synchronization-method-was.html but that didn't help me so much as I didn't quite understand both his issue and resolution.

Hopefully someone can give me some hints.

Thanks!

Comment: Updating a threaded application from 1.1 to 4.0, and not reworking the threading? That seems to be where the core issue is.

Comment: What is the type of `workQueue`?

Comment: The exception is generally thrown when you `Pulse` on an object whose monitor you don't currently own. Given that the surrounding `lock` statement explicitly enters the monitor for `this.workQueue.SyncRoot`, that's tough to accomplish. What does `Enqueue()` look like? And what type is `workQueue`? (If it's a custom type, make sure its `SyncRoot` implementation is returning a consistent object.)

Comment: There is something strange here: the original code enters a lock on `workQueue` and pulses on `workQueue.SyncRoot`: this is wrong and should trigger the exception you're seeing. However, your corrected code seems valid to me.

Comment: Sorry my network went down. Workqueue is a queue object (.net type), and enqueue is a method on that. I would really like ideas so I can roll off this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using your own thread pool mechanism. Then the exception probably because the thread has changed after the `lock` and before you call `Monitor.Pulse`. according to msdn this exception will throw at `Pulse` if:

> The calling thread does not own the lock for the specified object.

**Edit:**  Or you are locking in different thread after your first lock, "maybe at the producer thread that will dequeue the `WorkItem` and start them in the pool, you are calling `lock (this.workQueue.SyncRoot)`" at that thread before reaching `Monitor.Pulse(this.workQueue.SyncRoot);`.

Comment: Ends up there was a thread locking the "object" hidden deep in the code.  Changed it to lock the SyncRoot instead and all is well.

Comment: Glad you find it. this bugs usually hard to find ;)